# Three Even Columns Stacking Verticaly Instead of Horitzontally

Tags: html, css

I'm a new with HTML and CSS (so please be easy on me), and am having difficulty with my three even columns. They are stacking vertically instead of horizontally. I have a media query in place so that they stack after 400 pixels wide (email is currently built out at 600 pixels wide).

I've done research on similar topics, but some of it is still over my head. I don't believe I am using the BootStraps CSS. Would someone mind taking a look?

This is the HTML:

```
<!-- Start 3 Even Columns -->
<div class="container section">
<p><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/434319/GDPR%20-%20Opt%20In/Flat_Newspaper_100px.png" style="max-width: 100px; margin: 0px auto; display: block;"></p>
</div>
<div class="container section">
<p><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/434319/GDPR%20-%20Opt%20In/Packaging_NewProduct_FlatIcon_100px.png" style="max-width: 100px; margin: 0px auto; display: block;"></p>
</div>
<div class="container section">
<p><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/434319/GDPR%20-%20Opt%20In/Megahorn_100px.png" style="max-width: 100px; margin: 0px auto; display: block;"></p>
</div>
&nbsp; <!-- End 3 Even Columns -->
```

This is the CSS that I am referencing (this is built in HubSpot):

```
/* Three Even Columns */
.container:after { /*clear float*/
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
 }
.section {
 float: left;
 width: 33.3333%;
 border: 1px solid;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 @media (max-width: 400px) { /*breakpoint*/
 .section {
 float: none;
 width: auto;
  }
  }
```

EDIT: Okay, I have tried formatting the columns based on your feedback (hardcoded, not Bootstraps since HubSpot is stripping a lot of the .css), and I believe that some of the parent elements are overriding it. I have included all of the code from the email. Any idea what parent element could be causing this?

```html
<div style="display: none; font-size: 1px; color: #fefefe; line-height:       1px; font-family: Open Sans, Century Gothic, CenturyGothic, Geneva, AppleGothic, sans-serif; max-height: 0px; max-width: 700px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden;">Lorem ipsum dolor que ist</div>
    <table style="width: 100.038%;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="mobile-padding" style="background: #ffffff url('bg.jpg') repeat scroll 0% 0% / cover; width: 100%;" valign="top" bgcolor="#7b7573" align="center"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
                <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                <![endif]-->
    <table style="max-width: 600px;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
    <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 129px;">
    <td style="padding: 0px; height: 129px;" valign="center" align="center">
    <h1 style="font-size: 40px; color: #7b7573; font-family: 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, Geneva, AppleGothic, sans-serif; font-style: light; letter-spacing: 8px;">HEAD TEXT HERE</h1>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 50.25px;">
    <td style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px; height: 50.25px;" valign="top" align="center"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/434319/GDPR%20-%20Opt%20In/Artboard%201.png" alt="GDPR - Data Stock Image" style="width: 600px; max-width: 600px;" width="600" height="400"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]--></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="padding: 0px 0px 25px; font-family: Open\ Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; width: 100%;" valign="top" align="center">
    <table style="max-width: 600px; width: 730.617px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td style="font-family: 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, Geneva, AppleGothic\ sans-serif; font-size: 14px; padding: 10px; line-height: 25px; width: 863.617px;" align="center">
    <p>text text text text text text</p>
    &nbsp;
    <p>text text text text text text:</p>
    <!-- Start 3 Even Columns -->
    <div class="containersectionI">
    <p><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/434319/GDPR%20-%20Opt%20In/Flat_Newspaper_100px.png" style="max-width: 100px; margin: 0px auto; display: block;"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="containersectionII">
    <p><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/434319/GDPR%20-%20Opt%20In/Packaging_NewProduct_FlatIcon_100px.png" style="max-width: 100px; margin: 0px auto; display: block;"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="containersectionIII">
    <p><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/434319/GDPR%20-%20Opt%20In/Megahorn_100px.png" style="max-width: 100px; margin: 0px auto; display: block;"></p>
    </div>
    <!-- End 3 Even Columns --> <!-- end HubSpot Call-to-Action Code -->
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td style="border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px; padding: 25px; width: 863.617px;" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]--> <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
                <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                <![endif]-->
    <table style="max-width: 600px;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td style="padding: 0 0 5px 0;" valign="top" align="center"><img src="litmus-wheel-grey.png" style="display: block;" width="35" height="35" border="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="padding: 0; font-family: 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, Geneva, AppleGothic, sans-serif; color: #999999;" valign="top" align="center">
    <p style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;">6text text text text text text<br> text text text text text text <br><br> <a href="http://litmus.com" style="color: #999999;" target="_blank">View Online</a> &nbsp; • &nbsp; <a href="http://litmus.com" style="color: #999999;" target="_blank">Unsubscribe</a></p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: `<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-4'>One</div>
        <div class='col-md-4'>Two</div>
        <div class='col-md-4'>Three</div>
    </div>
</div>`

Comment: In bootstrap, rows go in containers. Columns go in rows. There are always 12 columns in bootstrap so for three columns, they would have the class `col-md-4`, meaning "column, medium sized, 4 spaces wide". No custom CSS needed if you're using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Add these properties to it:

```css
div.containersectionI{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
div.containersectionII{
    position: absolute;
    left: 135px;
    top: 0px;
}
div.containersectionIII{
    position: absolute;
    left: 260px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="containersectionI"><p><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/434319/GDPR%20-%20Opt%20In/Flat_Newspaper_100px.png" style="max-width: 100px; margin: 0px auto; display: block;"></p>
</div>
<div class="containersectionII"><p><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/434319/GDPR%20-%20Opt%20In/Packaging_NewProduct_FlatIcon_100px.png" style="max-width: 100px; margin: 0px auto; display: block;"></p>
</div>
<div class="containersectionIII"><p><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/434319/GDPR%20-%20Opt%20In/Megahorn_100px.png" style="max-width: 100px; margin: 0px auto; display: block;"></p>
</div>
```

Hope it helps :)

Edit: This might make it work, with `!important`, maybe?

```css
div.containersectionI{
        position: absolute !important;
        left: 0px !important;
        top: 0px !important;
    }
    div.containersectionII{
        position: absolute !important;
        left: 135px !important;
        top: 0px !important;
    }
    div.containersectionIII{
        position: absolute !important;
        left: 260px !important;
        top: 0px !important;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="containersectionI"><p><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/434319/GDPR%20-%20Opt%20In/Flat_Newspaper_100px.png" style="max-width: 100px; margin: 0px auto; display: block;"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="containersectionII"><p><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/434319/GDPR%20-%20Opt%20In/Packaging_NewProduct_FlatIcon_100px.png" style="max-width: 100px; margin: 0px auto; display: block;"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="containersectionIII"><p><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/434319/GDPR%20-%20Opt%20In/Megahorn_100px.png" style="max-width: 100px; margin: 0px auto; display: block;"></p>
    </div>
```

I know that most websites say that `!important` overrides almost anything, and to use it is not recommended, but in desperate situations (kind of) like this, you may use this.

Hope it helps again :)

Comment: this was very helpful, but I still have some parents elements overriding this code, I believe. I have no idea what could be causing it. I have revised my question to include the full code of the email. Do you mind taking a look? Thanks again fro your help!

Comment: Ok I will see. :)

Comment: @JackieAngela Does this work? I tried my best to help.

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish the columns easily using Bootstrap. You just need to pattern your html tags like so:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I made a plunk that uses only bootstrap to achieve 3 even columns here for your reference:
https://embed.plnkr.co/TisOnM9Lb1ZmonleBKN3/